# Comparing one dataset to another dataset in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

> I have two data set in my code. I need to compare that second data set
>   with first data set My first data set returns this result below:-

**FirstDs**:-

```
MaxUpdatedPrepped       MaxUpdatedSent          MaxUpdatedStamped  

1900-01-01               1900-01-01               1900-01-01
```

And my second data set returns below:-

**SecondDS**:-

```
MaxUpdatedPrepped       MaxUpdatedSent          MaxUpdatedStamped  

1900-01-01               1900-01-01               2014-11-11
```

I need to compare that both result and return alert like "Not matched" if the both first data set value is not match with second data set value. I tried a lot but i could get only wrong answer

```
For i As Integer = 0 To DsMaxDates1.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
    Dim found As Boolean = False
    For j As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        If DsMaxDates1.Tables(0).Rows(i)(0).ToString = ds.Tables(0).Rows(j)(0).ToString Then
            found = True
        End If
    Next
    If found = False Then
        ASPNET_MsgBox("Another User Working in Same Account. Please Click Reset.")
    End If
Next
```

This above result returns true instead of false.

Comment: first dataset value `1900-01-01` is equal to `1900-01-01` so its return true

Comment: try `DsMaxDates1.Tables(0).Rows(i)(0).ToString = ds.Tables(0).Rows(j)(0).ToString and DsMaxDates1.Tables(0).Rows(i)(1).ToString = ds.Tables(0).Rows(j)(1).ToString and DsMaxDates1.Tables(0).Rows(i)(2).ToString = ds.Tables(2).Rows(j)(0).ToString`

Answer (score 2):

You should *never* change the type of your data unless it's *absolutely* necessary. Treat dates as `Date`, integers as `Integer`, strings as `String`, decimals as `Decimal`, etc. The `ToString` method is mostly used when you want to display the data to the user.

With that being said, you're not comparing datasets, you're comparing datatables.

The reason as to why it returns `True` is because you only compare the first column. You need to compare all the columns. If your table doesn't contain complex data types like byte arrays then the simplest way is to use [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) combined with [Enumerable.SequenceEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348567(v=vs.100).aspx).

The following code assumes that each table contains the same number of rows and columns.

```vb
''Uncomment to unleash the one-liner:
'Dim notEqual As Boolean = (From i As Integer In Enumerable.Range(0, DsMaxDates1.Tables(0).Rows.Count) Where (Not DsMaxDates1.Tables(0).Rows(i).ItemArray.SequenceEqual(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).ItemArray)) Select True).FirstOrDefault()

Dim notEqual As Boolean = (
    From i As Integer In Enumerable.Range(0, DsMaxDates1.Tables(0).Rows.Count)
    Where (Not DsMaxDates1.Tables(0).Rows(i).ItemArray.SequenceEqual(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).ItemArray))
    Select True
).FirstOrDefault()

If (notEqual) Then
    ASPNET_MsgBox("Another User Working in Same Account. Please Click Reset.")
End If
```

---

You can expand this even further by creating a reusable extension method:

```
Public Module Extensions

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Function SequenceEqual(table1 As DataTable, table2 As DataTable) As Boolean
        Return (((((Not table1 Is Nothing) AndAlso (Not table2 Is Nothing))) AndAlso ((table1.Rows.Count = table2.Rows.Count) AndAlso (table1.Columns.Count = table2.Columns.Count))) AndAlso ((table1.Rows.Count = 0) OrElse (Not (From i As Integer In Enumerable.Range(0, table1.Rows.Count) Where (Not table1.Rows(i).ItemArray.SequenceEqual(table2.Rows(i).ItemArray)) Select True).FirstOrDefault())))
    End Function

End Module
```

Then you can simply do as follows:

```
If (Not DsMaxDates1.Tables(0).SequenceEqual(ds.Tables(0))) Then
    ASPNET_MsgBox("Another User Working in Same Account. Please Click Reset.")
End If
```